# How do I iterate through rows in a specific column, find a value, and add a count = 1 to another column if it finds that value?

Tags: python, pandas

CURRENT:

```
df = {'Evaluation': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Maybe'], 'Total': ['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

EXPECTED:

```
df = {'Evaluation': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Maybe'], 'Total': ['1', '0', '0', '1']
```

For each time the value "Yes" or "Maybe" appears in column "Evaluation" I'd like to give a count = 1 to column "Total"

My current code:

```
for k in df['Evaluation']:
    if k == 'Yes' or k == 'Maybe:
    df['Total'] = 1
```

But this code just puts "1" to all the rows in Total.

Comment: can you show sample `df` and expected output?

Comment: Does it need to increment?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath nope, it doesn't need to increment

Comment: then check it out my solution that works

Comment: Use `df.loc[~df["Evaluation"].isin(["Yes","Maybe"]), "Total"] = 0` to assign the 0s directly. You don't need to `apply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
df["Total"] = df["Evaluation"].apply(lambda x: 1 if if "Yes" in x or "Maybe" in x else 0)
df
```

If you have a `list of values` to check with then,

```
df["Total"] = df["Evaluation"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in ["Yes","Maybe"] else 0)
df
```

Comment: @marvinrae you can upvote myf answer if it helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will set all rows to 1 when you say `df['Total']=1`.

If you want a new column to be a function of the values in a different column, best to use .apply() like so:

```
df["Total"] = df['Evaluation'].apply(lambda x: int(x in ("Yes","Maybe")) )
```